# How to get google pixel 6 emulator skin?

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

Can anyone tell me how to get android 12 google pixel 6 and 6 pro emulator skins for developing?
I couldn't find any solution on internet, therefore asking this question of stack overflow.

Answer (score -7):

Open the Android Studio and go to the "AVD Manager"->"Create Virtual Device" section.

- Select "New Hardware Profile"
- Set Screen size - 6.4, Resolution - 1080x2400, RAM 8GB, everything else as default, click on "Finish"
- In the next step select "Android 12.0" image and click "Next"
- Lastly, make sure that "Device Frame" is enabled and click "Finish"

Comment: not what I wanted.

Comment: I can see that the OP wanted a skin, but I just needed the screensize and this was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Screen dimensions should be 1080 x 2340 https://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/5f5557c5